# Does boost::combine() work with output of a method?

Tags: c++, boost

In the test case below, I use boost::combine to iterate on output of a function `getPoints()`.

**Expected Output**

I expect (1, 2, 3) printed 6 times; since I effectively zip two lists -

([point, point, point], [point, point, point]).

**Actual Output**

The output is surprising to me, and wrong. The first two lines are off suggesting memory corruption?

```
(0, 0, 3)          // <-- wrong!
(52246144, 0, 3)   // <-- wrong! memory corruption?
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

This can also be verified online here, http://cpp.sh/622h4.

Is this a bug?

Code below -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>


struct Point {
    int x, y, z;
};

const std::vector<Point> getPoints() {
    // There is only one Point in the entire code, which is (1, 2, 3).
    const Point point = {1, 2, 3};
    // Return a vectore of 3 copies of the point (1, 2, 3).
    return {point, point, point};
}


int main() {
    // Zip over two copies of 3-tuples of {1, 2, 3}.
    for (const auto& zipped : boost::combine(getPoints(), getPoints())) {
        auto p1 = zipped.get<0>();
        auto p2 = zipped.get<1>();
        // Expected output is (1, 2, 3), six times.
        std::cout << "(" << p1.x << ", " << p1.y << ", " << p1.z << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(" << p2.x << ", " << p2.y << ", " << p2.z << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behavior here as you access a dangling reference. This can be fixed by

```
const auto points1 = getPoints();
const auto points2 = getPoints();

for (const auto& zipped : boost::combine(points1, points2)) {
    // ...
}
```

Rvalue references are always problematic when dealing with range libraries. Obviously, a range algorithm like `boost::combine` doesn't copy the argument. And it creates a new proxy range object, which makes it impossible to extend the lifetime of the temporary range passed in.

Contrary, a range-based for loop `for(const auto& item: getPoints()) {...}` expands to

```
{
    auto && __range = getPoints();
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

where the lifetime of `getPoints()` is extended by binding it to an rvalue reference. Imagine a function template `combine` as

```
template<class Rng>
auto combine(Rng&& rng) {
    auto && == range; // Nice try but doesn't help

    // ...

    return someProxyRange;
}
```

This function template can't do anything about extending the lifetime of `rng`, as it acts in a different scope than `rng`, which comes from the client side. In a range based for loop, this is different. The scope of the temporary (e.g. `getPoints()`) and the forwarding reference `auto&& __range` are at the same scope, hence the lifetime can be extended.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the dangling reference is? If you would have used `const auto zipped` would that have worked as well?

Comment: Thanks! Why is the reference lost here if I use the function directly? I expected combine to internally store a copy of the result - that doesn't seem to happen. Is this expected? (Ack on the second `0`, fixed.)

Comment: For example, `for(const auto& point: getPoints()) {...}` should work properly. Why does it fail with `combine(...)`?

Comment: @KalEl Look at [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and the following sentence: *If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the forwarding reference __range, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within range_expression is not extended.* You create temporary vectors by `getPoints`.

Comment: @rafix07 That should be in the answer/another answer.

Comment: Sorry for the slow, incremental edit. I hope it's clear now?

Comment: Yep, no worries! I am getting back to c++ after a long hiatus, and this helps. I had a hunch that this could be due to implementation detail of combine, your response makes this class. Will also check out range-for.